# Is there a Python fn that mimics nvl() or can I use SQL to do it?

Tags: sql, python-3.x

I need to join two tables using python on an nvl type fn because we have one table where, based on the part type, we only put in the first 7 characters.

So far I have not found a simple way to do this in python.
Is there a function that will do this, or another easy way to achieve it?

Thank you in advance

I joined on part_number, removed where the other table's fields were NaN, then joined as a new table on the substring, then appended the tables together.  And ended up with the wrong number of rows.

```
left join on nvl(nvl(thistable.part_number, substr(thistable.part_number, 1, 7)),'not in defn table') = part_number.othertable
```

Output might be like this:

```
thistable.part_number    othertable.description
abc123                   real part
def456                   another real part
1234567-02               part stored as 1234567 in othertable
koue49c                  not in defn table
```

Comment: Sorry, that table example looks awful.  Not sure how to format as table in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `coalesce()`:

```
on coalesce(thistable.part_number, substr(thistable.part_number, 1, 7), 'not in defn table') = part_number.othertable
```

`coalesce()` takes multiple arguments, so you don't need to nest the function calls.

Comment: I ended up creating a function using a regex compare to do this.  Tried to use coalesce and was not successful.  Probably many ways to do it, but my function happened to get solved before I was able to get the coalesce to work.